# How to capture a video frame Exoplayer android

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, mediametadataretriever

I'm trying to capture video frames at specific points in a video using Exoplayer but this code always capture the first frame of the video. How do I fix it

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(yourPath);
Bitmap bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
```

Answer (score 2):

This method should get you the frame you want at the specific point

```
  public static Bitmap getVideoFrame(Context context, Uri uri, long time) {
    
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    
        try {
    
            retriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
            bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(time);
    
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    
        } finally {
    
            try {
    
                retriever.release();
    
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Still the same issue. Gives me the first video frame. I think I had to be due to getFrameAt() method converti the milliseconds in to microseconds. I'm not sure though

Comment: Yes same issue, it is giving the first frame even though the milliseconds time is changing.

Comment: Works fine. Time is in microseconds, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It was supposed to be milliseconds * 1000. Fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use seekto() function present in exoplayer to play video from any timestamp of video!

code to setup Exoplayer:

XML code:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/videoPlayerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

define these variables in you class:

```
private Context context;
private PlayerView videoPlayerView;
private ExoPlayer player;
String videoUri = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtvvideos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4";
```

Creating a function in your class to setupExoPlayer:

```
public void setVideoPlayer(long time) {
    player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
    //Bind the player to the view.
    playerView.setPlayer(player);
    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri);
    // Set the media item to be played.
    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    // SeekTo particular timestamp in videoPlayer
    player.seekTo(time * 1000);
    // Prepare the player.
    player.prepare();
    // Start the playback.
    player.play();
}
```

pass to your playerview id (XML id) and run the app! :)

// to start video from 0th second

```
videoPlayerView.setVideoPlayer(0);
```

// to start video from 10th second

```
videoPlayerView.setVideoPlayer(10);
```